# Android Studio Google Icons Import

Tags: android, icons

Google has a huge Icon collection. https://www.google.com/design/icons/
I want to make use of these Icons inside Android Studio. Is there a good way of downloading/importing those Icons without having to click a lot? Thanks!

Comment: How did you finally used them?

Answer (score 0):

- In "Android" View, click "res" => "drawable"
- Rightclick on "drawable"
- Select "New" => "Vector Asset" => "Choose ..."